# pass commands from file to heredoc

Tags: ssh, heredoc

This is my first post here. I was wondering if anybody could help me with my script.
I am trying to use a file with commands instead of commands in the scrip.
Here is the example of script i have now

```
ssh -T $_remote <<
    now="$(date)"
    name="$HOSTNAME"
EOL
```

and this is what i would like to use (if possible)

```
instructions="cat commands.txt"
ssh -T $_remote <<
    $Instructions
    name="$HOSTNAME"
EOL
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

variable instructions take the result of cat as string

```
instructions=$(cat commands.txt)
cat <<EOL
    $instructions
    name="$HOSTNAME"
EOL
```